# Is the US age gap of voting behaviour unprecedented, and will it lead to a drastic shift of the political mainstream in foreseeable future?

Tags: united-states, demographics, history

According to the Pew Research center, young people in the USA leaned heavily towards voting for Democrats in the 2018 election.
[image]
Notable are not only the 2018's (Compared to because of its historic turnout for a midterm election) margins, but the 2016's as well. Considering how [unfavorably](https://www.statista.com/statistics/516020/new-hampshire-democratic-primary-2016-exit-polls-votes-by-age/) Hillary Clinton fared with young people compared with Bernard Sanders, it is highly unlikely those would ever vote for a Republican candidate (And possibly they abstained from voting at all in 2016).

This should not mean only the young are unlikely to change their party in current times: [94%/96% of people who voted for the Republican/Democratic presidential candidate in 2016 will do so again 2020](https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2020/08/13/the-2020-trump-biden-matchup/screen-shot-2020-08-31-at-3-31-48-pm/).

```
   - Presidential Elections (Wikipedia) -
      Dem    Rep
2012: 60%    36% (Age 18-24)
      60%    38% (Age 25-29)
      55%    42% (Age 30-39)
      48%    50% (Age 40-49)
2008: 66%    32% (Age 18-24)
      66%    31% (Age 25-29)
      54%    44% (Age 30-39)
      49%    49% (Age 40-49)
2004: 54%    45% (Age 18-29)
      46%    53% (Age 30-44)
2000: 47%    47% (Age 18-24)
      49%    46% (Age 25-29)
      48%    50% (Age 30-49)
```

As far as I could find numbers, this "blue-shift" started in 2008, as before then the youth didn't vote that differently from the rest of the country, or it swung every few years.

**Is this age gap unprecedented since WW2 in the United States, and can we assume it to be a persistent change of views in the American public? What ramifications - if any - will it cause in the foreseeable future?**